# Why my losses are in thousands when using binary_cross_entropy_with_logits without sigmoid beforehand?

Tags: pytorch

My straining step:

```
import torch.nn.functional as F

weight = torch.ones((4, 56, 96, 96))
weight[:, :, 30, 30] = 100.

label = torch.zeros((4, 56, 96, 96))
weight[:, :, 25, 25] = 1.

out = mynetwork(input) # shape is (4, 56, 96, 96), network arch is UNET

loss = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(out, label , pos_weight=weight)
```

Here's my losses during training:

```
Epoch [0], train_loss: 0.620761, val_loss: 9160599.391018, val_err: 7.204710
Epoch [1], train_loss: 1559.895434, val_loss: 40458.054621, val_err: 8.831522,
Epoch [2], train_loss: 5888.181579, val_loss: 120648.662376, val_err: 8.057971
Epoch [3], train_loss: 81293.656826, val_loss: 35877.424359, val_err: 7.935688
Epoch [4], train_loss: 94574.528814, val_loss: 69056.008745, val_err: 12.674819
```

I didn't apply any sigmoid to the output `out` of the network (last layer is `conv2d`). According to pytorch doc:

> input – Tensor of arbitrary shape as unnormalized scores (often
> referred to as logits).

That means I don't have to apply sigmoid beforehand. However if I goes ahead and apply the sigmoid anyway, my losses dropped below 1 and they are decreasing in contrast to the losses above! What's the possible reasoning behind this?

Comment: You may like to provide more details such as models and training pipelines. I can't reproduce the issue on my side.

Comment: After doing some checking, the `out` has max value that greater than 1 (1000-10000), does this mean my network have errors? Should the output be less than 1? Should I normalize the output beforehand? I couldn't find anything that catch my eyes.

Comment: I would argue this has to do with your training method (optimizer, most certainly learning-rate, batch_size, etc..). As you said `F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits` includes  a sigmoid function inside it. Don't be tempted to apply an additional sigmoid just because the training seems to work better.

Comment: @Ivan I actually might agree with you after the inspection. What's your opinion on my comment above?

Comment: For context, the network is Unet

Comment: @Ivan You are absolutely right, I just decreases the learning rate by multitude of value and the losses dropped below 1, I didn't know this could affect the loss so much. Thank you for your insights!